# email url hostname parse php

Tags: parsing, url

I'm trying to parse the hostname url inside my php to get an email, but I'm not getting the url hostname. See the code below. I do not know what I'm doing wrong here. **{$baseURL}**

```
// hostname variable
$baseURL = $SERVER['SERVERNAME'];

$message_contents = "Greetings ".trim($fullName).".\n\nPlease follow the link below to reset your password.\n\n{$baseURL}/ssp/resetssp.php?token=".$token."\n\n(*Please do not reply to this email.)\n\nIf you did not request that your password be changed.\n\nThank you,";
```

Here is the email I'm getting without the hostname parse.

```
/ssp/resetssp.php?token=WF5IMKKT7AZCV5V19CRKSWWCA7PM7PCE
```

I would like to get the output like this:

```
https://domainname/ssp/resetssp.php?token=WF5IMKKT7AZCV5V19CRKSWWCA7PM7PCE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` depends on what you need. This article explains the difference between them: [SERVER_NAME Versus HTTP_HOST](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host). So, try using this code:

```
// hostname variable
$baseURL = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$message_contents = "Greetings ".trim($fullName).".\n\nPlease follow the link below to reset your password.\n\n{$baseURL}/ssp/resetssp.php?token=".$token."\n\n(*Please do not reply to this email.)\n\nIf you did not request that your password be changed.\n\nThank you,";
```

Comment: Already set my variables, but is not parsing the {$baseURL}. That article only show you when to use either one. I still need to parse the {$baseURL} into my line in my code.

Comment: I got it to work.  `$baseURL = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: If you are loading that php file via HTTP then $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] has a value, but if you are running your code without using an HTTP server, your server variables will not have a value.